# How can I check which face of spherical polyhedron corresponds to a given euler angle?

Tags: angle, polyhedra

I am specifically mapping a dodecahedron to a sphere and I am trying to get if a rotator is within the boundaries of a given face.

[image: spherical dodecahedron]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Find the distance of point $P$ from the centers of the 12 faces, and choose the closest.